# Tool to analyze a software project and extract information about the source code

Tags: windows, software-development, open-source

I am looking for a program to analyze a software development project (i.e. a folder) and output information about the source code:

- total number of lines
- total number of files
- average files size
- number of lines/percentage of different languages
- runs on Windows

It should support a wide range of languages; at minimum (a bit flexible though):

- Javascript [crazy unlikely bonus: sub detects jQuery specifics]
- HTML/XHTML
- PHP
- Python
- CSS
- C++
- Markdown
- JSON
- XML

Bonus points for:

- Being able to analyze a local (or remote) code versioning system (GIT and/or SVN).
- (If option above supported) Ability to find number of lines/percentages by author as well as language.
- Being cross platform.
- Easy extendability to support custom languages.
- 'Pretty' graphical output as well as text output.

Comment: Is this code that you want to analyse by any chance open source? There are a lot of services that offer this analysis for free to OSS projects but you have to let them have a peep at your code and publish the results.

Comment: @Caleb *Sort of*/Some: It is for quite a few (ie based on curiosity more than anything else) of my own projects - most of which I do make OS when I'm happy with the quality/version 1. However some are not OS for various reasons - such as contract work.

Answer (score 1):

What you look like is typically a clone of the front page of GitHub project indicating some software statistics, no ?

If so, i would direct you to this answer on StackOverflow : [How to generate stats for a GitHub project?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6611200/15619) which in turn leads to [gitstats](http://gitstats.sourceforge.net). To directly quote the former website, it provides

> Here is a list of some statistics generated currently:
>
> General statistics: total files, lines, commits, authors.
>
> Activity: commits by hour of day, day of week, hour of week, month of year, year and month, and year.
>
> Authors: list of authors (name, commits (%), first commit date, last commit date, age), author of month, author of year.
>
> Files: file count by date, extensions
>
> Lines: Lines of Code by date

It unfortunatly requires git, Python and Gnuplot, so i guess it will be more easily usable on Linux systems.